# bxSlider v3.0 - Horiztonal page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I seem to have a Javascript issue with my bxSlider v3.0.

http://skyllanweb.co.uk/

The page is scrolling horizontally quite a lot and I have little to no knowledge with JS issues.

Can anyone shed any light?